# NYSE & NASDAQ: Mkt Cap: $1 billion+

Tags: stocks, investing, yahoo-finance

I am looking for an online source to get all NYSE and NASDAQ stock symbols representing companies with a market cap of $1 billion or larger. I have looked at this [screener](http://screener.finance.yahoo.com/b?sc=&im=&prmin=&prmax=&mcmin=1000000000&mcmax=&dvymin=&dvymax=&betamin=&betamax=&remin=&remax=&pmmin=&pmmax=&pemin=&pemax=&pbmin=&pbmax=&psmin=&psmax=&pegmin=&pegmax=&gr=&grfy=&ar=&vw=1&db=stocks) from yahoo finance, but it includes foreign exchanges and would be to much work to regularly screen all the stocks to weed out the foreign exchanges. The goal is to get the tickers into a database.

Comment: Welcome to SE, John. We hope you come back with more questions, and discussion. If you ask another question, it's good to wait a bit before awarding "best answer." A full day or 3-4 answers is a good start, although you change the best choice if more answers come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Google Finance [Screener](http://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener) ; you will be able to filter for NASDAQ and NYSE exchanges.

Comment: +1 because this screener meets the criteria I asked. Unfortunately, I don't see a way I can programatically get the tickers off the JavaScript-generated paginated pages. I will edit the question.